# Is it possible to connect two ESX host directly without physical switch?

Tags: networking, vmware-esxi, vmware-esx

I have two physical hosts without switc and single WAN connection.
host B running many backup software and other tools.
Is it possible to connect two ESX host directly without phisical switch?

Look at the chart, is it possible?
There is more sensible to do so?

[image]

Comment: I guess it's your idea to use the DD-WRT virtual machine as a router for the virtual machines on Host B?

Comment: yes  joeqwerty, I use it to share the Internet connection
If you have another solution, want to know please

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. If you have to connect only two interfaces, you can just run a single network cable between the two interfaces instead of connecting each interface to a switch. With recent network interfaces (any Gigabit, for example), you can use a normal network cable. With older network interfaces that do not have the [auto MDI-X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medium-dependent_interface) feature, you need a [crossover cable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable).